# Closing incoming connection in Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, connection

I've got a script which receives large file uploads via a PUT request. These files have some processing done on the fly as they are uploading. Sometimes we can detect that a file is invalid in the first few bytes so we `die()` with an error message. The only problem is that the client still sends the rest of the data which is a huge waste. Is there a way to shutdown the incoming connection?

Code:

```
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'rb');

// Do some data checking here
if( <invalid> ) {
    fclose($fp);
    die('Error');
}
```

`stream_socket_shutdown` looked like it might do the job but it has no effect.

Is there any way to do this? Even if I have to write an extension just for this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to give the following a shot and see if this terminates the connection properly:

```
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'rb');

// Do some data checking here
if( <invalid> ) {
    fclose($fp);
    header("Content-Length: 0");
    header("Connection: close");
    flush();
    die('Error');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give this a try and report back.